# java no sabe tratar el objeto

Tags: java

```
 static int n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"introduzca 
 un 
 numero para verificar si es primo"));

public boolean calcularNumero(int dividendo,int divisor,int aux) {       
//cocientes,calcular numero primo,dudas con divisor

        int dividendo1=aux;
        divisor=dividendo;
        aux=divisor;
        int numero3=dividendo/divisor;
        if (numero3==divisor && numero4==divisor) {
            return primo=true;
        }
            else    if (numero3==aux && numero4==aux) {
                return primo=true;


            }


    return primo;

}

public boolean esPrimo(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
    Arrays_aelatorio arra=new Arrays_aelatorio();
    arra.esPrimo(n);
    System.out.println("el valor del numero para saber si es primo"+arra);
```

//la salida por pantalla es la siguiente una @ seguido de numeros
//el valor del numero para saber si es primohola.Arrays_aelatorio@323b36e0

Comment: Tienes que explicar cual es el problema. Con poner solo el código no es suficiente.

Comment: @CGG te respondió. La salida que te esta dando es por que no tienes sobre escrito el método toString() de la clase.

Answer (score 2):

Si te lo saca en ese formato, posiblemente es que te esá imprimiendo la dirección en memoria de lo que intentas imprimir. Lo que tienes que hacer es incluirle a tu objeto el método toString(). De esta manera, cuando lo quieras imprimir por pantalla, automáticamente se llamará a este método e imprimirá lo que especifiques ahí.

Aquí tiene sun ejemplo. Como ves, es público y puedes retornar y hacer dentro de él lo que quieras. Te puse varios ejemplos del return comentados.

```
public String toString(){
   return "Este array es primo";
   //return variable;
   //return "nombre: "+variable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, lo que está haciendo es imprimirte la posicion en memoria del Array.

Si lo que quieres es imprimir los elementos del Array, lo que debes hacer es ir recorriendo con un bucle for cada una de sus posiciones y a su vez imprimiendolas con System.out.println().

Algo como esto, mas o menos:

```
Array array = new Array();
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
   System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```